# Gradle init not generate build from pom

Tags: gradle, pom.xml

I'm trying to init a Gradle build from a `pom.xml` file. The follow structure is created, but I noticed that `buid.gradle` is missing.

```
my-project
-- gradle
---- wrapper
------ gradle-wrapper.jar
------ gradle-wrapper.properties
-- src
-- pom.xml
```

Here's my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>

    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>

                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cdm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>${wsimport-phase}</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <xnoAddressingDataBinding>true</xnoAddressingDataBinding>
                            <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                            <target>2.1</target>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>${osb.url.prefix}MyService${osb.url.suffix}</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>via-osb</id>
            <properties>
                <wsimport-phase>generate-sources</wsimport-phase>
                <skip-clean>false</skip-clean>
                <osb.protocol>http</osb.protocol>
                <osb.host>my.host</osb.host>
                <osb.port>80</osb.port>
                <osb.url.prefix>${osb.protocol}://${osb.host}:${osb.port}/path/to/osb/</osb.url.prefix>
                <osb.url.suffix>v102?wsdl</osb.url.suffix>
            </properties>
        </profile>          
    </profiles> 

</project>
```

Am I missing something? The `gradle init --type pom` commad ends without errors...

Comment: try adding `--info` or `--debug` to the gradle command?

Comment: @RaGe both return `Unknown command-line option`

Comment: @RaGe hmm, installed Gradle outsite STS, it worked. Will see the output...

Comment: Just a hint - try to use the gradle wrapper instead of your local gradle installation. If a pom.xml is availabl it is ok just to call `./gradlew init` according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html (chapter 15.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some diff or bug with the STS plugin, I just installed Gradle and it worked. Also, `Run As > Gradle Build` not recognized the option `--info` in the init command.

Here's the info output

```
gradle init --info --type pom
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\master\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\my-project\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'my-project']
Evaluating root project 'my-project' using build file 'C:\my-project\build.gradle'
.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'init' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':wrapper', task ':init']
:wrapper (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:wrapper
Executing task ':wrapper' (up-to-date check took 0.168 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:wrapper (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.656 secs.
:init (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:init
Executing task ':init' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Maven to Gradle conversion is an incubating feature.
:init (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.386 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And the STS output

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      init
[sts]      --info
[sts]      --type
[sts]      pom
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :init from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--info'.
```

Comment: I would highly recommend moving to buildship http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship